# CORS allowed custom authentication filter | Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a weird requirement to authenticate requests using nothing but a cookie. There is a main service written in PHP and it's sessions are handled using a cookie called `PHPSESSID`.

```
                   ┌─────────┐
                   │         │
         ┌─────────┤ Browser ├───────────────┐
         │         │         │               │
         │         └─────────┘               │
  ┌──────▼─────┐                  ┌──────────▼──────────┐
  │            │                  │                     │
  │ PHP Server ◄──────────────────┤ Spring Boot Service │
  │            │                  │                     │
  └──────┬─────┘                  └──────────┬──────────┘
         │                                   │
         │                                   │
         │         ┌───────────┐             │
         │         │           │             │
         └─────────► Database  ◄─────────────┘
                   │           │
                   └───────────┘
```

Small part of the services used by the web application is served from Spring Boot service. Now I want to authenticate the requests coming to the Spring service using PHP session id. At the same time I want to allowe the CORS. But when the custom security filter is enabled, requests sent from web application fails due to CORS error.

#### WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // When following custom authentication filter is added to the filter chain, 
        // requests from browser will fail due CORS error
        // without it, everything just works fine
        http.addFilterBefore(new MainAppAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.csrf().disable() //
                .authorizeRequests() //
                .anyRequest().permitAll() //
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

#### MainAppAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class MainAppAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        var httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        var cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();

        // check the session with PHP service
        var user = userIsValid(cookie);

        if(user != null) {
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getName(), null,
                            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRole()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            var httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendError(401);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I enable CORS when using custom authentication filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and().httpBasic();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        // Configure your Cors COnfig
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

And after this add http.cors() to your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be how I added allowed CORS methods and allowCredentials.

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

For some reason without `cors()` in the security configuration, POST requests from Chrome browser will fail (works on Firefox though).

```
http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```